# Selecting records between two timestamps

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I am converting an Unix script with a SQL transact command to a PostgreSQL command.

I have a table with records that have a field `last_update_time`(xtime) and I want to select every record in the table that has been updated within a selected period.

Say, the current time it `05/01/2012 10:00:00` and the selected time is `04/01/2012 23:55:00`. How do I select all the records from a table that have been updated between these dates. I have converted the 2 times to seconds in the Unix script prior to issuing the psql command, and have calculated the interval in seconds between the 2 periods.

I thought something like

```
SELECT A,B,C FROM table
WHERE xtime BETWEEN now() - interval '$selectedtimeParm(in secs)' AND now();
```

I am having trouble evaluating the `Parm` for the `selectedtimeParm` - it doesn't resolve properly.

<sub>Editor's note: I did not change the inaccurate use of the terms `period`, `time frame`, `time` and `date` for the datetime type `timestamp` because I discuss that in my answer.</sub>

Comment: `select * from your_table where tstamp between '2021-04-01' and now();`

Answer (score 79):

This works:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   tbl
WHERE  xtime BETWEEN timestamp '2012-04-01 23:55:00' AND LOCALTIMESTAMP;
```

`LOCALTIMESTAMP` being the SQL standard way of saying `now()::timestamp`.

Note the standard ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` which is unambiguous for timestamps with any locale or [`DateStyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting.

The first value for `BETWEEN` must be the smaller one. If you don't know what to expect, use [`BETWEEN SYMMETRIC`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparison.html) instead. (But that can result in a less efficient query plan.)

**However**, Postgres timestamps aren't discrete values, and `BETWEEN` includes lower *and* upper bound. Rather [avoid `BETWEEN` with timestamps](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29) and use this instead:

```sql
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   tbl
WHERE  xtime >= timestamp '2012-04-01 23:55:00'
AND    xtime <  LOCALTIMESTAMP;  -- excluding upper bound (optional)
```

To operate with a **count of seconds as `interval`**, just multiply the basic interval quantity:

```sql
...
WHERE  xtime >= LOCALTIMESTAMP - interval '1s' * $selectedtimeParm
AND    xtime <  LOCALTIMESTAMP;
```

In your question you refer to the data type `timestamp` as "date", "time" and "period". In the title you used the term "time frames", (now updated to "timestamps"). All of these terms are (were) wrong. Freely interchanging them didn't help, either. I had a hard time  understand it.
That, and the fact that you only tagged [psql](/questions/tagged/psql) (the problem hardly concerns the command line terminal) might explain why nobody answered for days.

Understand the data types `date`, `interval`, `time` and `timestamp` - with or without time zone. Start by reading the chapter ["Date/Time Types" in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

Error message would have gone a long way, too.

Aside: more often than not, the type `timestamptz` should be preferred over `timestamp`. See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Comment: I found my answer: select * from TABLE where record_time BETWEEN $from_datetime AND NOW(); Thanks

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is looking for the fix to this.  You need to remove timestamp from the where clause and use BETWEEN!

```
TABLENAME.COL-NAME-FOR-TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2020-01-29 04:18:00-06' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```