# Using BETWEEN operator with timestamp values in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, operators, between

Recently I've been informed by a StackOverflow user that using `BETWEEN` operator with values of data type `timestamp without time zone` **should not** be used.  Below is the quote.

> Between means >= and <= and shall not be used with ranges that contain timestamps.

When asked for an explanation of this thesis or a link to Postgres documentation where it states that I've got an answer saying

> Why would such a simple thing need a site with documentation. I am sure you can find many anyway if you google (at least my detailed posts on various forums demonstrating the case)

Well I googled. And found nothing that would advise against using this operator with timestamp values. In fact [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8860632/2095534) on SO uses them and so does [this mailing group post](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20070813143728.GA91805%40winnie.fuhr.org).

I was informed that all these years I was doing it wrong. Is it really the case?

As far as I know Postgres max precision for a timestamp is `1 microsecond` - correct me if I'm wrong. Thus aren't below statements equivalent ?

```
sample_date BETWEEN x AND y::timestamp - INTERVAL '1 microsecond'
```

and

```
sample_date >= x AND sample_date < y
```

*Edit*: The sample is just a consideration of the difference. I'm aware of the fact that developers can miss the time part, but assuming one knows how it behaves, why should it **not be used**? Generally speaking, this is merely a sample, but I'm wondering about the bigger scope. I've been investigating the planner and it seems to be parsing `BETWEEN` to `>= AND <=`.

Why does one preferably write `>= AND <=` than `BETWEEN` in the matter of **results** - not including the time to translate it?

Comment: The second is way preferable.  It makes no assumptions about the underlying implementation (plus it is shorter and easier to read).  Here is a blog post about the use of `between` in SQL Server.  Many of the points also apply to Postgres:  https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your input. This example is just to consider difference between both statements. Main question here asks whether or not that user was right pointing me that BETWEEN should not be used (generally) with timestamps - not the mentioned case only. I'll make sure to read that article, thanks again.

Comment: You can use it, but it is clumsy and ugly, and since it uses the epsilon `t BETWEEN a AND b - epsilon`, it will depend on the epsilon. The mathematical convention with an half-open interval `t >= c1 AND t < d1` is much clearer, IMHO. Also: it is stackable, without overlap: `t2 >= c2 AND t2 <d2` will combine just fine with the (c1,d1) case into `t >= c1 AND t < d2` whenever `c2=d1`

Comment: @joop thanks for your comment. But then again - this sample was just to prove the point. Generally, the last question is the matter I'm worried about, and IMHO I shouldn't be . . .

Comment: @KamilG. . . . It should *not be used* because it is less clear and more prone to error.  Experienced programmers try to avoid such constructs when they are trying to write maintainable code (and perhaps one day  move off to a different project).

Comment: @GordonLinoff even for implementing simple `>= and <=` case? Isn't it equal and cleaner?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with using `ts BETWEEN validfrom AND validto` instead of `ts >= validform AND ts <= validto`. They are the same.

I can only guess, but I'd say that the warning targets something different, namely whether either of the (identical) clauses above are the right thing to use.

Now this of course depends on what you are trying to do, but very often clauses like this are used to identify the one valid row for a particular timestamp. In that case the clause as above is wrong, because for a value of `ts` when the row was changed, you would get *two* results.

Consider this:

```
CREATE TABLE names (
   id integer PRIMARY KEY,
   val text NOT NULL,
   validfrom timestamptz NOT NULL,
   validto timestamptz NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO names VALUES (1, 'Smith', '1985-05-02 00:00:00', '2009-01-30 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO names VALUES (2, 'Jones', '2009-01-30 00:00:00', 'infinity');
```

This is meant to be a historized table of names for a person.

If you use a `WHERE` clause like above to query for the name valid at a certain time, it would work well for

```
SELECT val FROM names
WHERE current_timestamp BETWEEN validfrom AND validto;
```

But it would do the wrong thing for

```
SELECT val FROM names
WHERE '2009-01-30' BETWEEN validfrom AND validto;
```

That is because the end point of the interval of validity for a name is *not* part of the interval. For this case, it would be correct to write:

```
SELECT val FROM names
WHERE '2009-01-30' >= validfrom AND '2009-01-30' < validto;
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that the question was about __generally advising against using BETWEEN with timestamps__. Your example presents something I'm well aware of. I even wrote it that the precision of Postgres timestamp is 1 microsecond. Both statements presented by you are not equal in terms of result, but in my example they are. :-)

Comment: I answered your question in the first paragraph --- there is no problem whatsoever with using `BETWEEN`. The rest is just an attempt to explain why the notion might have come up that there is something wrong with `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Thanks. If that is the case, then it seems that someone didn't actually understand me . . .

Comment: In my experience, the pattern that's far more common is SELECT ... WHERE created_at BETWEEN '2000-01-01'::timestamp AND '2000-01-01 23:59:59'::timestamp, which is broken in several subtle ways.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a reference the SO user would have shared:
[https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This)

[image: Don't use BETWEEN with timestamps]

I used BETWEEN with two timestamps in a recent query and it worked but took much longer than expected. So, I can't verify any specific issue except, perhaps, performance; although this could be due to my giant data set.

I retried the same query with the `>= timestamp1 AND < timestamp2` pattern and performance was about the same.

I suppose a real concern here might be using timestamps without timezone and being sure you're getting the right records?

Answer (score 0):

> sample_date BETWEEN x AND y::timestamp - INTERVAL '1 microsecond'

... might actually still be broken due to leap seconds. But lets ignore that...

IMO the biggest reason not to use BETWEEN is because what it tells the database to do doesn't actually match the way our brains interpret it. If I say "it happened sometime between Jan 3rd and Jan 6th", most (or at least many) people will translate that into the interval "[Jan 3rd, Jan 6th)", which is definitely NOT what you get with the SQL expression "BETWEEN 'Jan 3rd' AND 'Jan 6th'". So even though that SQL expression has a completely defined meaning, that meaning conflicts with how most/many people read it in English. But if you use >= AND <, there's absolutely no question about what the intention is.