# Convert INT INTO DATE to calculate AGE

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, type-conversion, date-math

I have a problem with a query on PostgreSQL. I have a case for school where I need calculate the age of a person when he register for school on 1st Septembre of 2005. In a file I have their date of birth and only the YEAR of school registration.

The year registration is a int type ('2005') but I need to convert it to 01-09-2005 (DD-MM-YYYY) which is the start of the school year. How can I do this ?

- Should I convert it necessary into a date type if I want to calculate the difference between the date of registration and the date of birth ?
- If yes, how can I convert it in order for the date of birth to be on the date type and have a format '01-09-2005'.

I have an answer but that's not the way I should do it :

```
SELECT AGE('01/09/2005', auditeur.date_nais)
FROM auditeur
JOIN inscription ON auditeur.id_auditeur = inscription.id_auditeur
```

What I want is to replace the '01/09/2005' with `annee` ('2005') which is an `int` type.

Comment: Why not [ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) instead of this ambiguous form? That could be read as January 9th or September 1st.

Comment: Because in France we read it differently dates are on a format DD-MM-YYYY and even in programming our teacher wants us to do it this way..

Comment: Your programming teacher is being stubborn. The entire industry has standardized on ISO 8601. They should get with the program. The reason for this standardization is so we don't have to deal with weird nonsense like France having a preference for a particular date that conflicts with other countries that prefer MM-DD-YYYY for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how you get the desired `date` from an `integer`:

```
(2005 || '-09-01')::date
```

The concatenation force-converts `2005` to `text`. Use ISO 8601 format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Then the cast to `date` does not depend on the current [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting.

```sql
SELECT age((i.annee || '-09-01')::date, a.date_nais) AS age_at_registration
FROM   auditeur a
JOIN   inscription i USING (id_auditeur)
WHERE  a.id = 123; -- select person somehow
```

Related:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942824/how-to-concatenate-columns-in-a-postgres-select/19943343#19943343)
- [Selecting records between two timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723523/selecting-records-between-two-timestamps/8860632#8860632)

Comment: Thank you it worked !! Now I know how I can do it, it helped me a lot thanks 

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to generate a string to then convert to a date. You have 3 integers: annee from a table and constant values 09 for month and 01 for day. With these just use the [make_date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-datetime.html) function which takes 3 integers and returns a date.

```
select  age( make_date (annee,09,01), auditeur.date_nais)
from auditeur 
join inscription 
  on auditeur.id_auditeur = inscription.id_auditeur
```

Comment: Thank you it also worked ! I’ve tried your query as well and it worked so thanks a lot 