# How to get 1 row before and 1 row after what query specified?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, postgresql

Imaging a query that delivers "posts" in a specific time period between "from" and "to". A simple query.

Additionally, I need to get ONE record BEFORE and ONE record AFTER what the original query specified.

For example, a table holds these posts:

```
1 hello  20.08.2023
2 hi     21.08.2023
3 please 22.08.2023
4 bye    23.08.2023
```

For `get_posts("from" => '21.08.2023', to => '22.08.2023')` the origin query delivers:

```
2 hi
3 please
```

Now I need to add one row before (`1 hello`) and one row after (`4 bye`). Possibly as subquery inside the original query?

I read about window functions or subqueries, but I do not know how to start.

Comment: A [mcve] would make this much clearer. Also remove non-related tags.

Comment: Do you work with Postgres or MySQL. Please specify *one*. And your version number. The best solution may depend on it. Also, the exact table definition matters. Provide a `CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming current **Postgres**.

```sql
( -- one lead
SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE  time_stamp < '2020-08-21'
ORDER  BY time_stamp DESC
LIMIT  1
)  -- parentheses required

UNION ALL  -- core rows
SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE  time_stamp >= '2020-08-21'
AND    time_stamp <  '2020-08-24'  -- !

UNION ALL
( -- one lag
SELECT *
FROM   posts
WHERE  time_stamp >= '2020-08-24'
ORDER  BY time_stamp
LIMIT  1
)  -- parentheses required
```

Typically, you don't need an outer **`ORDER BY`** with this. But consider:

- [Are results from UNION ALL clauses always appended in order?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/316818/3684)

Unless the table is trivially small, you need an **index** on `posts(time_stamp)` to make this fast.

[Beware of `BETWEEN`](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29) when working with timestamp types. What you show looks like `date`, but `timestamptz` would make a lot more sense for the use case.

Always use **ISO format** with date and time literals, which is unambiguous with any locale and `datestyle` setting. The meaning of `'20.08.2023'` depends on settings of the current session and breaks easily.

Related:

- [Given a date/time range, how to filter results by time range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73793690/given-a-date-time-range-how-to-filter-results-by-time-range/73794968#73794968)
- [BETWEEN with datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425853/between-with-datetime/12426809#12426809)
- [Selecting records between two timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8723523/selecting-records-between-two-timestamps/8860632#8860632)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT post_id, post_date
FROM (

--All posts between the timeframe
SELECT post_id, post_date
FROM posts
WHERE post_date BETWEEN '2020-03-04 19:19:34' AND '2020-03-06 19:19:34'

UNION
--One before the from date
SELECT post_id, post_date
FROM posts
WHERE post_date = (
    SELECT MAX(post_date)
    FROM posts
    WHERE post_date < '2020-03-04 19:19:34'
)

UNION
--one after the to date
SELECT post_id, post_date
FROM posts
WHERE post_date = (
    SELECT MIN(post_date)
    FROM posts
    WHERE post_date > '2020-03-06 19:19:34'
)
) AS combined_posts
ORDER BY post_date;
```

You can also make the query shorter by using lag and lead functions instead of subqueries.

Comment: You should be using `UNION ALL`, instead of `UNION`, to avoid the unnecessary de-dupe. Also, it is not necessary to turn the UNION into a derived table. It won't make any difference to performance in this case, as the temporary table is needed for the sort anyway. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dkEd2NbX)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).